# Not able to get error value from props in Async submit validation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

My submit action in my react-redux app is as follows

```
export function submitDetails(details, callback) {
return(resolve, reject) =>{
        axios.post(URL, {
        "email": details['email'],
        "name": details['username'],
        "password": details['password']
    }).then((data) =>{
            callback();
            console.log("Success", data);
            resolve(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        // console.log('error here', error.response.data.message);
        console.log('error', error.response);
        reject(error.response)
    })
}
}
```

The console prints the error successfully in this case if the email is already registered. However, when I try to print the same error on the users form as bellow

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                        <Field
                            name="username"
                            lable="Username"
                            type="text"
                            component={ renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            lable="Email"
                            component={ renderField }
                        />
                        {console.log("cheki...",error)}
                        hahahaah{error}
                        {error  && <strong>{error}</strong>}
                        <Field
                            name="password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Password"
                            component={ renderField }
                        />
                        <Field
                            name="confirm_password"
                            type="password"
                            lable="Confirm Password"
                            component={ renderField }
                        />
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={submitting}>Register</button>
                        <Link className="btn btn-danger" to="/login">Cancel</Link>

                    </form>
```

the error is never printed.
i.e `const {error, submitting, handleSubmit} = this.props;` the error variable is always null. Is there something I am doing wrong???

Comment: `error` is never passed as a prop?

Comment: yes I am not able to access it

Comment: Where do you pass it as prop though is the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want validation just `onSubmit`, you should use [Submit Validation](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/submitvalidation/) instead.

If what you want is really Async Validation, I can see two errors in your code.

1. You are not throwing an error;

```
    catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error.response);
      // you should throw an error here, for example:
      // throw { username: 'That username is taken' }
      reject(error.response)
    })
```

2. You are getting `error` wrong. You should do:

```
    const {
      meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error },
      submitting,
      handleSubmit } = this.props;
```

Refer to [this great example](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/asyncvalidation/) from `redux-form` docs.